# Delete duplicates based on timestamp difference - If other rows with given ID exists with timestamp max 10 sec. later, delete them

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a smart meter data table like this:

```
#   Spalte      Typ         Kollation   Attribute   Standard
1   id          int(11)     Nein        kein(e)     AUTO_INCREMENT 
2   channel_id  int(11)     Ja          NULL 
3   timestamp   bigint(20)  Nein 
4   value       double      Nein        kein(e)
```

All values come from smart metering sensors:

```
id      channel_id  timestamp   value
17294   6 [->]  1360154653709   474.2
17295   10 [->] 1360154653709   19669893
17296   6 [->]  1360154672997   643.5
17297   6 [->]  1360154674760   608.8
17298   6 [->]  1360154676566   602.8
17299   10 [->] 1360154672997   19669893.3
17300   10 [->] 1360154674760   19669893.6
17301   10 [->] 1360154676566   19669893.9
17302   6 [->]  1360154678519   566.7
17303   10 [->] 1360154678519   19669894.2
17304   10 [->] 1360154680210   19669894.4
17305   6 [->]  1360154680210   396.9
```

Channel_id 6 is actual consumption, this one I will keep in every second. Channel_id 10 is the meter counter, every hour 1 value would be enough but the sensor gives it every second.

I want to create a recurring routine that detects and deletes "duplicates".

A duplicate is a row after the current row with the same channel_id and a given maximum timestamp difference, e. g. +10 sec. or +1 hour.

With this I try to reduce the amount of data to what I need to keep for good graphs.

Comment: Can you explain why you have duplicate channel_id at all?

Comment: Hm, so - according to your spec with 10 seconds, if there's a time stamp at 0s, one at 8s and one at 11s, 11s should be deleted because 8s exists and 8s because 0s exists, leaving only 0s?

Comment: Marcin: I have tried several ideas from this source but none of them deleted multiple duplicates or just grouped by 10s so that 10:29:09 and 10:29:10 were not recognized as duplicates.

Comment: Buttle: The Smart meters leave a record on each measured event. So for example, my electrical power counter tells the actual consumption and the counter value every second. My Gas counter leaves one tick every time the "6" of the 1/1000 passes the counter window.

Comment: Joachim: yes you are right, but when there is another record from 1-9 second(s) before the one with 0 all others have to be deleted except that one. I know it`s tricky but that's the problem i face...

Comment: Ich habe jetzt folgendes probiert, siehr bisher ganz gut aus:
`DELETE FROM  data WHERE id IN (
SELECT * 
FROM (

SELECT id
FROM  data t1
WHERE EXISTS (

SELECT 1 
FROM  data t2
WHERE t1.channel_id = t2.channel_id
AND t1.channel_id =8
AND t1.id > t2.id
AND t1.timestamp <= t2.timestamp +10000
)
) AS tmp
)`